# How can I create multiple inputs for a matlab function block?

Tags: matlab, simulink, sample

I want to restrict the variable that I use as input for a matlab function block, it must be only able to increase. 
To achieve that i have tried to compare the variable and the previous sample of it in a matlab function, but i don't know how to create two inputs. To solve that i've tried to use a mux, but then i get an error. And google doesn't give me an explanation how to use a mux signal as input for a matlab function.
So that leaves me here with this low-level question.
Thanks in advance for your help and time. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use multiple variables in a function, you need to modify your function declaration at the first line of your function.  The reference syntax is:

```
function [y1,...,yN] = myfun(x1,...,xM)
```

where x1 through xM are inputs.  Your declaration with two inputs might look something like:

```
function [returnValue] = hasIncreased(previousSample, variable)
```

[See the Matlab Function Documentation for more information.](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html?refresh=true)

Comment: Thanks, somebody else already answered the same, but that answer was deleted for unknown reasons.